# Use formvalidation on entire form after page reload from submit

Tags: php, jquery, formvalidation-plugin

I'm coding some basic validation (mainly for aesthetic purposes, will do the main stuff in PHP) with formvalidation, and I've noticed a big problem in that once I hit submit, if it goes back to the same page, all the fields are no longer validated. I've tried a couple of lines of code from googling the problem, but none seemed to work.

Here is one line that seems to run on the datepicker alright when you use it, but if I just stick it out in the option for the document ready function (I just use trial and error with jquery), it does nothing.

```
$('#main_form').formValidation('revalidateField', 'pcn');
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001028/validate-form-on-load) I tried this:

```
$('#main_form').validate().form();
```

But for some reason the entire validation breaks when I use that.

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hkkjwv8/) using the jquery code I'm using, what I basically want is it to instantly say that the field is required when you hit run.

Alternatively, can I set it to default to a certain message? That way I have PHP validate it on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working after a lot of trial and error. It turned out to be quite a simple fix, but needed to be in the correct place.

Add this line below all the validation code:

```
$('#form_id').formValidation('validate');
```

I'm hiding it behind `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`, so it'll revalidate the form on submit, but not validate when you first load.